Flutter/Tensorflow missmatching shapes error
I'm making a flutter app running a tensorflow Lite model. I got the following error:
Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 2] to a Java object with shape [1, 215].
Backstory: My trained algorithm uses 215 columns and outputs 1 or 0. Below you can find a screenshot using netron.app: Netron graph
I cannot understand why the thing wants to copy the shape [1,2] (output) into the input Java class. The code for this is so high level that I cannot debug it properly. I can't find my way around the Tensorflow Lite documentation for flutter, it only describes input arguments of the function breaking the code. Below is the function that is breaking, the error is in the runModelOnBinary() function. Any general direction/help/experience?
void evaluateModel() async {
    try {
           

      // Generate random input data with 215 columns to match the expected input size of 860 bytes
      List<double> inputData = List.generate(215, (index) => Random().nextInt(2).toDouble());

      // Convert List<double> to Float32List
      Float32List inputBytes = Float32List.fromList(inputData);

      // Convert Float32List to Uint8List
      Uint8List inputUint8List = inputBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
      print(inputData);
      // Run the model on the input data
      var output = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
        binary: inputUint8List,
        numResults: 2, // Adjust this as necessary
      );
      print("here2");
      // Handle null or empty output
      if (output == null || output.isEmpty) {
        var result = output?[0]; 
/* ChatGPT told me to do so, previously was taking the output var as the printable result. 
I don't think there is much difference for this issue as it's after the code breaks*/
        setState(() {
          _output = "Predicted: ${result['label']} (${result['confidence']})";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _output = output.toString();
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Catch any errors and display them
      setState(() {
        _output = "Error running model: $e";
      });
    }
  }

I have tried adjusting the numResults argument, looking at documentation and even chatGippidy, which suggested to do var result = output?[0], put everything is too vague and doesn't go into how this particular stack works.

I can suggest you to try with  tflite_flutter which is updated than the one you use.

After some more refactoring and general brain trauma, this suggestion worked. I'm  not sure how to flag a reply as a solution.
